# Pointer to function in union

Tags: c, visual-studio

Visual Studio gives me error in this code

```
typedef union
{
  double value;
  double (*UnFunc)(double);
  double (*BiFunc)(double, double);
  double (*VarAssi)(vars_t *, elem_t, elem_t, error_t *);
  void (*FuncAssi)(custom_funcs_t *, elem_t, expr_t, error_t *);
  char delimiter;
} body_t;

typedef struct
{
  const char *name;
  int priority;
  body_t body;
} elem_info_t;

static const elem_info_t s_STD_UN_FUNC[] = {
  {"sqrt",   2, sqrt},
  {"sin",    2, sin},
  {"cos",    2, cos},
  {"tg",     2, tan},
```

And VS says (underlining function assignments)

> error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'double (__cdecl
>   *)(double)' to 'double'

But all types of pointers already exist in union type. Explicit type cast causes another error. What I should do in this case? Thank you.

Comment: Please show definition of sqrt, sin, etc.

Comment: What would happen if, in your `union`, you put `double (*UnFunc)(double);` first ahead of `double value;`? By the way, I hope you have a really good reason for using a `union`. They can be problematic (your code one case in point).

Comment: Error in that place will disappear, but in all other places with definitions by functions with another types errors will stay.

Comment: sqtr and others are from math.h

Comment: The posted code is missing the definitions of the types: elem_t, error_t, expr_t, custom_funcs_t , and the typedef for 'body_t` fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When initializing a union, the first member will be initialized by default if you don't specify which one.  That's where the error is coming from.

You need to use a designated initializer to specify which member to set:

```
static const elem_info_t s_STD_UN_FUNC[] = {
  {"sqrt",   2, { .UnFunc = sqrt}},
  {"sin",    2, { .UnFunc = sin}},
  {"cos",    2, { .UnFunc = cos}},
  {"tg",     2, { .UnFunc = tan}},
  ...
```

Comment: @EveHo Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: this saved my day. Couldn't be a better answer :)

Answer (score 0):

the posted code contains several key missing elements.

The following shows an acceptable way to write the code

```
#include <math.h>

// set these following 5 typedefs to your actual types
typedef int error_t;
typedef int vars_t;
typedef int elem_t;
typedef int expr_t;
typedef int custom_funcs_t;

typedef union uFuncTypes
{
    double value;
    double (*UnFunc)(double);
    double (*BiFunc)(double, double);
    double (*VarAssi)(vars_t *, elem_t, elem_t, error_t *);
    void   (*FuncAssi)(custom_funcs_t *, elem_t, expr_t, error_t *);
    char   delimiter;
} body_t;

typedef struct funcStruct
{
  const char *name;
  int priority;
  body_t body;
} elem_info_t;

static const elem_info_t s_STD_UN_FUNC[] = {
  { "sqrt",   2, .body.UnFunc = sqrt },
  { "sin",    2, .body.UnFunc = sin  },
  { "cos",    2, .body.UnFunc = cos  },
  { "tg",     2, .body.UnFunc = tan  }
};
```

Note: for most debuggers, for proper display of the fields within the struct, and within the union, need to include an appropriate tag name in the definitions

the latest C standard strongly suggest NOT using `_t` at the end of type names as C likes to reserve that ending for it self.

Comment: thank you. I'll take cognizance of your remark.
We have _t in c education cource style. We write in c89 :)